# Audit failed: why? Reason was not given

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just failed this review, but I don't understand why. The question was shown without comments:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/34632397

I selected to provide "Feedback", because the question itself includes an answer and no real question was asked. So my proposed action would be to ask what the question is.

What would the desired review action be?

The discussion seems to point towards habits of the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag community. This leads to an interesting consideration for the audit system: are people expected to divine unwritten arcane "rules" when evaluating posts?

The same post without the upvotes would be considered bad under any other tag because it doesn't pose a question. The "system" determined it to be "good" because it got upvotes, but that simply acts as a feedback loop of objectively bad questions being allowed under [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).

Very black and white: as a newbie reviewer I could (temporarily) lose my reviewing privileges because [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) is holding itself to low standards and there is no way for me to know that these arcane rules exist.

Comment: The question is considered to be a "good" question, so selecting anything other than "look ok" would result in failure.

Comment: ... anything other than "looks ok" or skip*

Comment: Oddly, the user does have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76582987/2029983) on that post, but they completely omit their "solution". Is this some kind of [[tag:r]] oddity?

Comment: So just to be clear: a question without an actual question is OK? There was no question asked: it described a task with two solutions in the original post. I'm just very confused how a question can be "Good" if there is no question to begin with...

Comment: Judging by the fact that OP included a benchmark, they were probably looking for a more optimal solution (shorter/faster). They have provided *some* solution themselves, but it would likely be obvious to R users that this solution can be improved. Admittedly, it would have been better of OP said *"a naive"* or *"a sub-optimal"* solution.

Comment: The *system* determined it was a *"good"* (added emphasis on the quotes) question, @StephanT , because it has a score of 14 (+15/-1) (at time of writing). It does seem that what the OP is actually after is a less verbose solution, which was an implied question in the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76582182/1), however, they removed that.

Comment: A question without an actual question is not OK. I stopped doing reviews because this "STOP and listen" on bogus assessments based on some automated selection has completely demotivated me to work on any review queues.

Comment: The implicit question is *(How to) Find the first of the last 1's sequence(?)*. If we omit the solution in the question, I think that it's easier to see it as a question.

Comment: @ThomA the answer posted by OP is a benchmark of other solutions posted on their question. They have provided the benchmark for their solutions in the question.

Comment: A benchmark of other people's answers isn't though an answer, @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ . So they put *their* answer in the question (wrong) and then they posted an answer without an answer (wrong).

Comment: @A.L No, that's not the question being asked. The question is "How to find the first of last 1s *in the most optimal manner*". The fact that we disagree on the actual question is the very reason why questions **are expected to ask a question**, so that there's no room for interpretation or implication.

Comment: @ThomA yes and no. This has become an accepted form of providing an answer in [tag:r]. It helps you to choose between different solutions, so has some value. Although one can argue it is not "original", but again, call it [r] oddity if you will.

Comment: Why would you not add a benchmark as an edit to the answer, @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ ? The edit feature exists for a reason, and that would be a great use of it. An answer that contains *no answers* isn't an answer and doesn't belong in the answers.

Comment: @ThomA No. Adding a benchmark to each answer would not provide much value.

Comment: Then adding any benchmarks doesn't add value, @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ , just like an answer with no answer. If benchmarks add no value to an answer then an "answer" with just benchmarks has *even less* value as it contains no *answer*.

Comment: Feel free to downvote the answer (not close the question cc:@IanKemp). What you consider an answer differs on some cases between tags. Even an MRE in R is different from what you'd expect in most of other tags. Failing to see the differences, would result in curation actions that should not be performed and undermining the efforts of other contributors.

Comment: No, @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ, **that is not how it works at all**. You and the other members of `r` **do not** get to pretend that the rules that apply to everyone else, do not apply to you. I do believe that it is time for me to break my curation strike for `r` specifically, and impose some order on a tag that has very obviously come to believe it is a law unto itself.

Comment: @IanKemp I am not sure what are you referring to. First of all, the word "law" has a different meaning. If you mean rules, then we can discuss further. Second, you are free to use your privileges. But if it fall under some abuse, there may be repercussions. Third, if you don't agree with an answer, think it is NAA or plagiarism, downvote or cast del-vote, or flag it as such. Do not close the question.

Comment: If the question was not clear in its current form (I can agree to that), a very minimal edit (as I did) would've saved it. So your VTC was not valid.

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ a post *can* be closable before a minor edit and not after.

Comment: though.. i'd argue your edit makes it off topic.

Comment: @KevinB I can think of examples where a minor edits make a closable question, not closable, but not this one. For instance, where there's a typo, but the question is valid without that typo. And how would you argue that it is off-topic? You may say "efficient" is broad or opinion-based (which is not in my eyes, if the question is specific enough). But off-topic?

Comment: sorry, i used "off-topic" incorrectly, i more meant i could see someone closing it for that wording. Usually... when someone is looking for an iteration method that is "efficient", and or "fast", there's an objectively measurable thing you could instead describe to be clear what exactly you're looking for rather than... whatever the passing user decides "efficient", or "fast" means to them.

Comment: The question, as it was before, read "How do I achieve foo? Here is my solution to achieve foo." That isn't how questions on [so] work, it should just be "How do I achieve foo?" Then there should be a separate answer "You can achieve foo by doing bar. `Code example`." The question has now been changed to "I have been able to achieve foo by doing bar, however, it's not as performant as I'd like. What other methods can I use? This is my attempt doing bar `Code Example`." That is on-topic but the prior revision posted was *not* good as it was a Q&A in a Q; as written it should have been 2 posts.

Comment: @KevinB I understand. In this case, they have provided a toy dataset, information about the size of their actual vector, a solution that they have tried, benchmark of that solution, etc. But again, I understand your argument, and have applied that logic to close multiple questions on that basis myself. Cheers.

Comment: @IanKemp I also don't appreciate your tone. If you have evidence of abuse in `r` either flag it for mods or bring it up on meta. No one gets to point fingers and make baseless accusations.

Comment: I still don't understand why people in the R tag see this as such a stellar addition to the KB. Is this particular action something people routinely struggle with? is it a common need? or is it more of a fun interviewer challenge. To me it just looks like a data processing task specific to one user's needs that's unlikely to be directly relevant to someone else... but i'm not part of the R community, so, :shrug: I'd assume people just upvoted it because they found it fun to answer.

Comment: @KevinB I actually did that data processing task a month ago (I needed to find the index of the last rainfall event). Although I have not seen that question before today.

Comment: @ThomA I actually agree with your last comment. That is a good explanation. FWIW, I don't think this a good audit altogether. Cheers.

Comment: It doesn't technically/literally ask a question, but there's been a clear goal statement since revision 1. You could easily edit that to rephrase it as a question if that bothers you.

Comment: The title is **the question**, it is implied `"Find the first of the last 1's sequence"`, I read it as `"how do I find the first of the last 1's sequence?"`. In the body of the post they say "verbose" meaning "not optimal".

Comment: @zx8754 That is hard to understand for me, the question is about doing that "efficiently", which doesn't mean much, I believe. Efficiency of what? Speed? Memory? Cpu cycles? Smallest amount of lines? The current version mentions speed, but literally none of the answers contain benchmark, and very few of them explain why it would be fast.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier in R you can do the same thing in many ways. So new users end up using wrong function combos and make it too verbose (and possibly inefficient: memory, speed), so they ask "I have this, can you suggest better?". Another note, as far as I could tell, everyone who is against that post are users who never use R. <shrug>

Comment: I think it's not "against the question" as much as "in favor of some coherence" @zx8754. You can do the same thing in many ways in many programming languages, with various characteristics of speed and memory, nothing about that is specific to R, so why the special treatment?

Comment: And therein lies the problem. Some are injecting their own interpretation and meaning into a post's title where there is none. "Find the first of the last 1's sequence" is an imperative statement. It's beyond me how anyone could read a statement like this and think it's interrogative at all. If a post's title isn't directly a question, then I fully expect to see *a question* of some form in the post's body. I agree with Ian, users in specific tags can't make up their own rules and get upset when the rest of the community disagrees and holds the posts to the same site standards.

Comment: I didn't know that bountying a question is a good way to prevent it being closed.

Comment: @justhalf If it weren't for the strike, that would be a good reason to flag for moderator attention. Bountying a question just to prevent closure is an abuse of the system. Generally, moderators will rescind the bounty and close it. I don't know if it is an abuse that results in a suspension or a ban, but maybe it should.

Comment: And "efficient" isn't particularly descriptive either. Efficient in what way? Runs fast? Uses minimal resources? Is easy to write? Is easy to maintain? Quite often favoring one of the options is detrimental to the others, so you need to be explicit.

Comment: "objectively bad": At first revision, the question fits most of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (maybe not the "How to" missing in the title): It introduce the problem, gives expected output, and show research with what they done. I find it harsh to qualify it as objectively bad by in that regard.

Comment: @Tensibai At the moment of writing this, there are _11_ answers on that question. If, presumably, all of them allows one to do what's described, then it is objectively an opinion-based question. Please do not answer with the generic "R is so unique it can do things in different ways" others have tried to offer in explanation of this, that's true of so many programming language that also need to subject themselves to the rules of this website.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier indeed, and that's the root goal of SO, providing multiple solutions to one problem, a generic java question about filesystem access can be answered in multiple ways too and multiple answers should be welcome. I don't exactly get when quality answers has become a single answer in your heads to assess a question quality, the one in exemple is not stellar, but it's still far from bad. (I used java, but python, ruby, JavaScript, mostly all high level language could fit there). So yes, rules of this site isn't to block questions to get dozen of answer in fact....

Comment: @Tensibai Right, I cannot disagree with you on that, having multiple ways of doing something is valuable in many cases. I wonder if, however, there should be a threshold after which a question might qualify as "too-broad", or not limiting the context enough that there is a limit in the amount of ways it can be solved. "How can I serve an html document" has virtually infinite ways to be answered, and while a great many of those would be valuable to someone, it would not be useful on Stack Overflow, I believe, to have hundreds of pages of variations on that theme.

Comment: I understand that I am being hyperbolic here, as the question at hand does not feature hundreds of pages of answers, but it does seem that people would be able to add a couple more over all the existing ones, and that gives me pause.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier Well, let's keep hyperbolic: I think there's always a finite number of possibilities and I'd say "how to serve html" is indeed too broad and need to be narrowed down. As per Meta rules, an answer should be evaluated on its own merit, adding a threshold doesn't make much sense to me. Locking a question when there's too much answers piling on is something already doable by mod flag, because yes, it happens sometimes and is necessary. For the adding couple ones, the R community is pretty good at cleaning late answers and NaN in fact.

Comment: @justhalf I just saw your comment about my bounty. I wish you'd have mentioned me at the time instead of "shooting in the dark" (I didn't know sarcasm helps us discuss serious things, JK). I didn't bounty the question to prevent closure. This is not my first bounty to award existing answers, neither my first bounty on others questions. It won't be the last one either. If I wanted to prevent closure, I could've done it before it got closed not after it got reopened. Or I could've waited for 7 days instead of awarding the bounty after a day (again, not the first time that I award a bounty ASAP).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel please read above. Moreover, that question does not need to be closed, so if I was awarding a bounty to prevent closure, I probably would've gotten a slap on the wrist, but the question would've stayed open (maybe it would've been locked to stop users to act on the question because they are hyped up reading meta). Anyhow, if you still think I "acted with malice", please flag it. Strike will end and it will get handled at some point: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56478951

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ ah, no, I didn't tag you because the comment wasn't directed to you specifically (i.e., was not trying to berate you sarcastically), it's more of a general disappointment with the possible abuse of the system (I'm a designer for this kind of system on another website). Sorry I made it look that way. And yes, you awarding the bounty after 1 day certainly shows your sincerity.

Comment: @DrewReese, your claim about _imperative_ versus _interrogative_ is perhaps a nuance. My (personal) interpretation of imperative titles (lacking a literal question-mark, for example) is perhaps a terse way of presenting the problem statement, which is akin to asking a question (again, imo). I may find it too curt, contextually, but not so far from the notion of "must ask a question" that the ask-a-question metric fails. (The worst case of "imperative" to me is when somebody copies an assignment that uses imperative verbiage, but that's wrong for entirely different reasons.)

Comment: Is @IanKemp's opinion that *"`r` ... has very obviously come to believe it is a law unto itself"* wide-spread? I find that notion offensive (since I participate heavily in that tag), that's just me, but ... I also find it insensitive to the notion that the Stack community is full of "sub-cultures". There are many differences between groups of non-overlapping users, and on my infrequent jaunt into far-distant-tags (to me), I realize the expectations are often slightly different. Where is there any justification of this claim that [tag:r] is more different (and in a bad way) than any other tag?

Comment: @IanKemp Contrary to what this discussion seems to imply the rules for the [tag:r] tag aren’t in principle different from those of the rest of Stack Overflow. The picture of lawlessness that your comment and answer are painting is wholly inaccurate. It may be based on a simple misunderstanding. As an ancient contributor to the wider Stack Overflow I can categorically state that the [tag:r] tag has no specific, systemic moderation issues. If you believe otherwise the onus would be on you to demonstrate the opposite. Good luck.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You have fallen afoul of two things:

- the system that chooses questions for reviews operates solely on heuristics, particularly the number of upvotes a question has. There is no human feedback/selection into this system, apart from the ability to remove an unsuitable question, which almost always only happens after the fact.
- the bar for quality on Stack Overflow has continued to fall to the point that questions that are very obviously not, answers that are very obviously not, and anything in between that is quite obviously garbage, is not only not removed, but accepted. This is exacerbated by orders from Stack Exchange Inc. that preclude the removal of content that is similarly rubbish.

The end result is that there are far more rubbish questions that are highly upvoted, so the review system naturally ends up choosing more of said questions.

**You did the right thing.** A "question" that fails to ask anything *does not belong here*. It is the **asker's** responsibility to ensure they ask a question that can be **unambiguously** answered, **not** anyone else's responsibility to attempt to divine meaning from the tea-leaves that said asker has left there.

So, what can you do about this? *Literally nothing.* That's one of the reasons why, after voluntarily curating this site for years via the review queues, I no longer bother, because the system is so broken that it makes curating far more of a thankless chore than it should be.

Comment: `"A "question" that fails to ask anything does not belong here."` - I mainly follow R tag, and by this rule, ~60-70% would fail. What is a question by your definition? Is it a sentence with "?" mark at the end or is it a statement "do this", "do this better". To me questions are implied, there is no need for a question sentence. OP has a solution, and wondering if there are better/correct way of doing it - this is **the** question.

Comment: But that was *never* asked, @zx8754 . It was, *maybe* implied by their first revision, but the OP then removed that very vague implication, making the question *completely* questionless. [So] is for *specific* questions, not vaguely implied/completely omitted questions.

Comment: @ThomA be honest, how can you not "read" the question from that post? Title: "do this", question body: "I have a verbose solution", meaning "not the best", so you read it as "how do I do this better?"

Comment: The OP **removed** the verbose, as I have stated several times, @zx8754 . How else can I read a title "How do I do this,m" with a post that states "the solution is this" than the OP doesn't understand a Q&A format.

Comment: For reference, this is the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76582182/5) that I saw when this question (on meta) was posted, and that was also the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76582182/5) the OP saw in the review, @zx8754 . It very clearly appears as a title with a question, and a question that's isnt a question but an answer.

Comment: The point is, as high rep users we have privileges, most instead of improving and editing, prefer to downvote and close. That post has 10 answers, they didn't struggle to "read" the question. Even after edits, if you can see 10 answers, there must have been a question, don't you think? Maybe go and rollback instead of closevote and downvote.

Comment: And as high rep users we should be closing unclear questions until such time they are clear, which is why I voted to close it; it wasn't clear @zx8754 . That a badly written unclear question has 10 answers doesn't make it a well written clear question, it still badly written and unclear. Those answers (I'm not an SME in [[tag:r]] so impossible for me to know) could be on very different problems *because* the question is unclear; I've seen that happens in the tags I am familiar with, so I wouldn't not be surprised. As for downvotes I'm not sure where I said I did; I'd not voted other to close.

Comment: @zx8754 I often downvote and close many low quality posts, and move on. ***IF*** the post looks *close* to being salvageable with some minor edits by the OP then I may also leave a comment on what could/should be improved, and move on. Life is too short to spend training others how to clearly communicate their needs if they don't want to learn. If they put in minimal effort in posting, it's likely to be met with minimal effort to help.

Comment: @zx8754 Re _"To me questions are implied, there is no need for a question sentence."_, just no! Absolutely not. Why on earth do you endorse the the bar being set so absurdly low on SO that there is not even the requirement for a question to include a sentence that ends with `?`. Your comment astounds me.

Comment: @zx8754 There are two points of discussion:

1) I got an audit question to evaluate. The "correct" answer seems to be decided by community vote instead of objective metrics. Just because it has upvotes does not mean that the question factually meets certain standards.

2)  Overall standards for posting questions. I would argue that if average community evaluation is a valid measure of quality, the average quality will continue to reduce over time. The point of moderation is to _increase_ the quality to prevent exactly this.

Comment: On a related note: would it be possible to only show audit questions that have at least one tag matching a tag that the person posted at least X answers/comments on? Although I agree that [r] should not be treated differently, this would avoid frustration with the audit system.

Comment: @zx8754 Actually, the fact that the question has 10 answers may be a clue that's something wrong -- in general, haven't opened this one -- specifically because an unclear question tends to attract answers that are all over the place as each answerer is going for a different question. Also, if the code is working, and the OP is looking for criticisms/improvements, then the question may be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: In many years of programming I came to the simple conclusion. If you cant articulate the problem, it is that exact reason why you cant solve it.  If  someone writes long waffle and  maybe whines its not working but actual requirement is vauge or expected behavior not stated people make random guesses and sure, one may hit on the answer by chance, but 10 stabs in the dark doesnt mean it was a great question it just means 10 people had a possible opinion for an answer that might get them points

Comment: @BugFinder in this case all answers give the exact same result, with various performances differences about speed/maintainability. Given R has multiple packages aiming at the same functional results but geared toward different kind of input (volume/format). This is exactly the goal of SO IMHO: provide a knowledge base of how to perform a task, so there's no stab in the dark, even at first revision the question is understandable, it has input, desired output, and show a try at the task, I.e this question has a MCVE. Willing a sentence with an interrogation mark is clearly nitpicking here IMHO.

Comment: @skomisa: I don't think either the particular punctuation `?` or grammatical structure as a query is required.  I have asked several questions where I pretty much explicitly say "I'm looking for X." rather than "How do I X?"  What's important is being clear on what answers should provide.

Answer (score 3):

I would vote 'looks ok'.

The question that I asked has a reproducible example (in the first chunk of code), a clear objective ("to find the index of first 1 in the last sequence of 1s (indicated by ^ in the above code)") and shows my attempts (in the second chunk of code).

Admittedly, there are two things that could enhance the quality of the question.

First, I should not simply remove the term 'verbose' in the first edit. I was planning to replace the term 'verbose' with a better term, which I failed to find at the moments of first editing. I just changed the term to 'sub-optimal'.

Second, I should not add benchmark without providing more explanation. It was added to justify why I select the accepted answer. This can certainly confuse people with fresh eyes and thus I removed it.

Final note, Stack overflow has a huge community that consists of people with different culture, knowledge, standard and perspective. It is impossible to create a question or answer that satisfy everyone. Therefore, I would kindly encourage you to be broad-minded before making any *harsh* judgement.

Comment: I personally find that the benchmark, and its associated "fastest way to find the first 1 of the last 1 sequence" are the things that would sustain that question, because it's then actually answerable. Currently, it's a bunch of opinion-answers on how one finds it most elegant. At least, with benchmark and a target of speed, one can then choose an actual fastest answer.